# Unable to Connect from Flask to Postgres Docker Container

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask

I'm trying to connect a python flask application to a database inside a postgres docker container.

I have the below `database.conf`:

```
POSTGRES_USER=testdbuser
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=testdbpass
POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=testdb
```

and `config.py`:

```
import os

user = os.environ['POSTGRES_USER']
password = os.environ['POSTGRES_PASSWORD']
host = os.environ['POSTGRES_HOST']
database = os.environ['POSTGRES_DB']
port = os.environ['POSTGRES_PORT']

DATABASE_CONNECTION_URI = f'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'
```

and finally `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  database:
    container_name: postgres-test
    image: postgres:latest
    env_file: database.conf
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

The error I'm getting after `docker-compose up --build -d` -> `export $(xargs < database.conf)` -> `export FLASK_APP=app.py` -> `flask run` is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: You are forwarding the port `5432` to your local machine (`localhost`) but trying to connect to a different host (`postgres`).

Comment: @Kendas can you please let me know where I have to make the change.

Comment: I'm crafting an answer.

Comment: Have you tried just setting POSTGRES_HOST  to ‘localhost’ rather than `postgres`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I just tried that and it worked. Pretty sure I've not understood this well. If I change it localhost, would I be able to access the same container (with persistent data) with `docker run` and `docker execute` in a different terminal?

Comment: Docker executes the instructions in an image (in this case - `postgres`) on your computer but sandboxed. It is not really related to the terminal you run the command on. What the `docker-compose` file is doing is creating an internal network where this process has the same hostname as the service name (`database`). It is also forwarding the port `5432` to your machine's `5432`. So any time you connect to the port `5432` on your local machine, you will hit the container through the forwarded port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error itself gives insight:

```
could not translate host name "postgres" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

The host `postgres` does not exist in DNS or your local network. `SQLAlchemy` is unable to connect to it. This logically the case, since you created a docker container and forwarded the port `5432` to your local machine.

There are 2 choices you can take - either use the `localhost` address to connect from the flask app or run the flask app as a docker-compose service.

## Option 1 - use `localhost`

The `POSTGRES_HOST` environment variable does not seem to be used by the `postgres` docker image. So you can just change this in the environment file:

```
POSTGRES_USER=testdbuser
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=testdbpass
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=testdb
```

## Option 2 - run flask using docker-compose

For this, you will need to create a simple `Dockerfile` and add the flask app to the `docker-compose.yml` file.

I suggest something simple for the `Dockerfile` like so:

```
FROM python

COPY . /app
# How you install your python packages may differ
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Ensure the path here is correct
ENV FLASK_APP /app/app.py

CMD flask run
```

Then you will need to add this to the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  database:
    container_name: postgres-test
    image: postgres:latest
    env_file: database.conf
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  flask:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:  # or use env_file as you did above
      POSTGRES_USER: testdbuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testdbpass
      POSTGRES_HOST: database     # This is the name of the database service in this file above
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
      POSTGRES_DB: testdb
    depends_on:
      - database

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

Hope this gets you going.